# (challenging sql)compare two tables for different value

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I want to compare values of `table a & c` and find differences.
We can specify `unique_key` of `table a` by compare `id` between `table a & b`,
and by matching `unique_key` of `table b & c`, we can compare `Name` of `table a & c`.

Can we get the list of rows that `Name` has different value for `table a & c`?

So If I write table,

```
table a 
+----+------+-----------+
| id | Name | int_value |
+----+------+-----------+
| a1 | aa   |         1 |
| a2 | bb   |         2 |
| a3 | cc   |         5 |
+----+------+-----------+
table b
+----+------+-----------+
| id | Name |unique_key |
+----+------+-----------+
| a1 | !!   |        u1 |
| a2 | @@   |        u2 |
| a3 | ##   |        u3 |
+----+------+-----------+
table c 
+----+------+-----------+
| id | Name |unique_key |
+----+------+-----------+
| c1 | aa   |        u1 |
| c2 | B1   |        u2 |
| c3 | C1   |        u3 |
+----+------+-----------+
```

As a result, I want to get

```
NameA NameC unique_key
bb    B1    u2
cc    C1    u3
```

I tried this sql, but none of them get me correct result.
What would you do?

```
SELECT a.Name, c.Name, b.unique_key
FROM a
INNER JOIN b
ON a.id = b.id
LEFT JOIN c
ON b.unique_key = c.unique_key
and NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM a WHERE a.Name = b.Name);
```

---

---

real sql(for real DB) I made

```
SELECT i.*, g.*, r.g_id
FROM i
INNER JOIN r
ON i.id = r.id
LEFT JOIN g
ON r.g_id = g.g_id
WHERE CAST('i.name1' as varbinary) != CAST('g.name1' as varbinary)
OR CAST('i.name2' as varbinary) != CAST('g.name2' as varbinary)
OR CAST('i.name3' as varbinary) != CAST('g.name3' as varbinary)
GROUP BY i.id
LIMIT 30;
```

error I got:

```
Error occurred.SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'varbinary) != CAST(
```

Comment: you can use `CONVERT(ColumnName, BINARY)`,

The `cast (ColumnName  as varbinary)` is correct but in SQL Server

Comment: Thanks It worked :)
May I ask one more thing? that sql worked well but getting slow query warning since there's 37million rows to scan lol

Comment: Is there way to make it efficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `cast` the `field` as `BINARY` before comparing

by default `aa` and `AA`, both are the same

```
SELECT i.*, g.*, r.g_id
FROM i
INNER JOIN r
ON i.id = r.id
LEFT JOIN g
ON r.g_id = g.g_id
WHERE CONVERT('i.name1' , BINARY) != CONVERT('g.name1' , BINARY)
OR CONVERT('i.name2' , BINARY) != CONVERT('g.name2' , BINARY)
OR CONVERT('i.name3', BINARY) != CONVERT('g.name3', BINARY)
GROUP BY i.id
LIMIT 30;
```

Comment: sorry I edited the table. 
`varbinary` only effects for aa, AA case right? but I have random character that can be `Name`.

Comment: Error occurred.SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'and cast

Comment: If you are using `MS SQL` 
you can use `CONVERT(ColumnName, BINARY)` instead of the `cast (ColumnName  as varbinary)`

Answer (score 1):

You seem to just want some joins and a comparison:

```
select a.name as nameA, c.name as nameC, b.unique_key
from a join
     b
     on a.id = b.id join
     c
     on b.unique_key = c.unique_key
where a.name <> c.name;
```

I don't see why a binary comparison would be needed for columns called `name`.  But you can use the `binary` keyword if that is really needed (it is not needed for your sample data).

Also, your question is specifically about names being different -- not about missing rows.  So, outer joins don't seem appropriate either.